# Sharepoint CSS : dynamically add SharePoint:CssLink using javascript/jquery

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, css, html

How to add CSS Link dynamically to  elements?

```
$('head').append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="my css path">');
```

The below code doesnt work because we need to specify the url/path of the css file.

```
$('head').append('<SharePoint:CssLink runat=”server” Version=”4″ />');
```

Comment: In my suggestion, you should use delegate control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CssLink-Control is a server-side control. Jquery is only client-side, you can´t do that using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The other option can be to add a custom action (A scriptlink) Using SharePoint 
JSOM

Answer (score 0):

Here's the "oldschool" way of doing it, which hopefully works accross all browsers. In theory you would use setAttribute unfortunately IE6 doesn't support it consistently

```
var cssId = 'myCss';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
if (!document.getElementById(cssId))
{
    var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = document.createElement('link');
    link.id   = cssId;
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'http://website.com/css/stylesheet.css';
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

This example checks if the CSS was already added so it adds it only once.

Put that code into a javascript file, have the end-user simply include the javascript, and make sure the CSS path is absolute so it is loaded from your servers.